# Undefined symbols upon bringing a static library into project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, linker-errors

I have a static library that I've created. It's a universal library so it should be working on the iphone and the simulator. Just by bringing the library into the project it won't compile, I get about 21 linker errors. They're all like this:

```
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NumberPad", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libClipPOSLibrary.a(PCCIDEntryView.o)
```

I've included all the frameworks necessary in the project, but for some reason this library just isn't happy. Also, I'm sure the architecture of the library matches the architecture of the project, and I've even used the nm command to look at the library to see if all of the classes are referenced and they are. 
    Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Thanks for the response, your answer led me to the right solution. There were a couple of libraries that I needed to add to "Link binary with libraries" I had just assumed cocoapods was handling that for me, but they did need to be added to my library before building the .a

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app doesn't need to know about NumberPad... it's your "libClipPOSLibrary.a". You should probably include / link the library that includes the NumberPad stuff (and the other missing symbols) against your "libClipPOSLibrary.a" when you build the .a file.